# Difference between $table->string('some_text'); & $table->text('some_text'); in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5

What is the difference between:

```
$table->string('some_text');
```

and:

```
$table->text('some_text');
```

in Laravel?

Please, if you can be comprehensive. Thank you.

Comment: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/schema lists the difference and their relation to DB column types. Please concretize which peculiarities need further explanation.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

As defined [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#available-column-types):

`$table->string()` uses a VARCHAR equivalent

`$table->text()` uses a TEXT equivalent

(The actual types can depend on the database system)

The obvious difference is that VARCHAR has a specified length (default with `string()` is 255 characters) whereas TEXT doesn't have that.

[Here is a comparison of the two types in MySQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/418)