# Laravel Migrations String (MySQL VarChar) vs Text - When to use them? How do they differ?

Tags: mysql, laravel, mariadb

Laravel's documentation on Migration Columns states support for Text or String types / columns. I'm unable to find an explanation of how the two are different, and therefore I don't know when I should use one over the other.

Comment: Rather than this question depending on laravel, it depends on the database whether it's mysql or mariadb [refer here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/blob.html)

Comment: [Refer this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28519294/13833218)

Comment: Thank you. Your second comment answers my question fully.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between $table->string('some\_text'); & $table->text('some\_text'); in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28519174/difference-between-table-stringsome-text-table-textsome-text-in)

Answer (score 0):

Laravel's documentation states the MySQL equivalent in the right column.

It states that String is the equivalent to VarChar in MySQL, which is [defined in their documentation here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/char.html). Basically it strips trailing spaces and there is a limit of 65,000 characters or so. So you could use it for basically anything. Ex. blog post title, or the body of the post, etc...

[Text in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/blob.html). It doesn't state that there is a character limit on Text in that documentation [but it does here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/storage-requirements.html), which is also about 65,000 (bytes, but each character is 1 byte from what I can tell).